# How to SELECT * WHERE JSON keys contain ANY/IN (array of values)

Tags: json, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-query

I am dealing with a Symfony "workflow" "Marker" and Postgres. (and Doctrine)

in the db, the column "status" contains JSON data like this

```
{"needs_address":1,"needs_contacts":1,"needs_education":1,"needs_health_and_social":1,"has_profile_photo":1,"has_letter":1}
```

I figured out how to query like this

```
SELECT id, profile_status, beneficiary_code
FROM public.beneficiary_profile
WHERE profile_status->>'needs_address' = '1'
```

How can I query for a list of status' like
 `('needs_education','needs_contacts','needs_address')`
without writing it all out like

```
WHERE profile_status->>'needs_address' = '1'
    OR profile_status->>'needs_contacts' = '1'
    OR profile_status->>'needs_education' = '1'
```

I figure there must be a way with JSON functions and maybe `IN()` or `ANY()`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to unnest the elements in order to be able to use an IN clause, something like:

```
select *
from public.beneficiary_profile p
where exists (select *
              from jsonb_each_text(p.status) as x(ky,val)
              where x.ky in ('needs_address', 'needs_contact', 'needs_education')
                and x.val = '1');
```